# Is there a way to set the default port when using the Ruby Fog Ge

Tags: ruby, fog

I am trying to use the fog gem to bootstrap a EC2 host that is listening for ssh connections on a different port than 22.  Is there a way to force fog to use a different port than 22?  I looked in the docs and did not see a way. I can change net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb to use the port instead of the default 22, but I didnt want to go that route if possible.  Is there a port param for fog that I am not seeing?  If someone has an answer and example that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that fixed the issue thanks for the reply.  If possible could you put that in the fog docs?  I cant one up your answer because I dont have enough rep points, but thanks again for the answer it was much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, would you be interested in making a pull request to improve the docs? I'm certainly happy to help you with any questions you might have, but would hate to take away a great opportunity to get involved if you would like to. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `server` object you should be able to do `server.ssh_port = other_port` and subsequent commands should do-the-right-thing.